# PHP Exec Command different result compare to command line

Tags: php, curl, exec

Hi Guys have you ever find this issue like me, the exec command working normally in localhost but in server its not working (for sure exec already activated since its returning a results) and the weird part if i run the command in command line in webserver it works as expected

Here's the command that i run

```
curl 'https://republic.gg/site/nav-bar-login' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'X-CSRF-Token: Znb-C1LpstugfYSM5r2RBZ9u9Fg0ATONOI8HraEDvmReRrw6Zrj6leQRvOez8tBH2jmZPHVZcr5040bZw0mIIw==' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary19bus3HleA69SVsg' \
  -H 'Origin: https://republic.gg' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: https://republic.gg/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.142817176.1601263531; _fbp=fb.1.1601263531949.2074251348; _gid=GA1.2.1723790011.1606234432; _csrf-frontend=d8c63e2a5db674f9949c6a6e579181a69f990617b005b2646ea2ff28bf62d02ba%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A14%3A%22_csrf-frontend%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A32%3A%2280B14QHNDl8kUOABEWmdAXA3LlAtbJ6G%22%3B%7D; advanced-frontend=s2qmjf372875a7ievs4pumthdr' \
  --data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary19bus3HleA69SVsg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrf-frontend"\r\n\r\nbuwmDuZSuxVeyaMZr5Ptk8X7oaCkcHvETdvcDLqObo4YpwtIoiHcWCyHykrn_qDJi6rmzMYcHfF-4pVD6f8C9A==\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary19bus3HleA69SVsg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="LoginForm[username]"\r\n\r\n123123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary19bus3HleA69SVsg\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="LoginForm[password]"\r\n\r\n123123\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary19bus3HleA69SVsg--\r\n' \
--compressed -i
```

Results when im executing this from command line in webserver :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 01:34:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload
Content-Length: 190
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"success":false,"data":{"status":false,"message":"Validation failed","error":{"username":["Incorrect mobile number or password."],"password":["Incorrect mobile number or password."]},"errorHtml":"<li>Incorrect mobile number or password.</li><li>Incorrect mobile number or password.</li>","dataLayer":{"label":"Incorrect mobile number or password. ,Incorrect mobile number or password.","msisdn":""},"totalAttempt":""}}
```

But simply when i run exec($str, $result) result only returning, results from webserver :

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 01:37:47 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
    [3] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
    [4] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [5] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    [6] => Pragma: no-cache
    [7] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
    [8] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    [9] => X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [10] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload
    [11] => Vary: User-Agent
    [12] => Content-Length: 0
    [13] => Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    [14] => Connection: Keep-Alive
    [15] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [16] => 
)
```

Results running in local :

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 01:40:43 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
    [3] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
    [4] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    [5] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
    [6] => Pragma: no-cache
    [7] => X-Frame-Options: DENY
    [8] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    [9] => X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
    [10] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    [11] => Content-Encoding: gzip
    [12] => Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains;preload
    [13] => Content-Length: 190
    [14] => Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    [15] => Connection: Keep-Alive
    [16] => Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [17] => 
    [18] => {"success":false,"data":{"status":false,"message":"Validation failed","error":{"username":["Incorrect mobile number or password."],"password":["Incorrect mobile number or password."]},"errorHtml":"<li>Incorrect mobile number or password.</li><li>Incorrect mobile number or password.</li>","dataLayer":{"label":"Incorrect mobile number or password. ,Incorrect mobile number or password.","msisdn":""},"totalAttempt":""}}
)
```

seems like theres no body response and i think some of the request just being change or else?

Appreciate if anyone can help bit clueless how to debug

Additional information webserver OS :

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Local :

```
macOS Catallina 10.15.5 using XAMPP
```